# SQL pivoting - How to get all possible combinations between multiple columns to be pivoted

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, combinations, multiple-columns

This is my source table (pivot_dummy):

[image: input data]

and I need to pivot it by Parameter_type but need all possible combinations between Parameter_val's. Something like this

[image: Desired Output]

I am using this code to get it done:

```
SELECT nct_id, [Asset],[Indication], rowid
FROM (SELECT nct_id,Parameter_val,parameter_type, rowid
      FROM (Select *,
                   Row_Number() Over (Partition By nct_id,Parameter_type ORDER BY nct_id) RowId 
            from [dbo].[pivot_dummy]
           ) a 
     ) s
Pivot (
    max(parameter_val)
        for Parameter_type in ([Asset], [Indication])
    ) as pivottable
```

But this is not giving me the desired output and is omitting various combinations for Asset/Indications in between. I am also not sure how it will work if more columns come in (which is very possible) and thus am looking for a generic solution which can find possible combinations among all the `param_type` columns based on the common `NCT_ID`.

Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This looks like you just need a standard pivot query.  Have you tried something yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is trickier than your previous question, because not all ids have all the values.

The temptation is:

```
select pd1.nct_id, pd1.parameter_value as asset, pd2.parameter_value as indication,
       pd3.parameter_value as BMx, pd4.parameter_value as LOT
from pivot_dummy pd1 join
     pivot_dummy pd2
     on pd1.nct_id = pd2.nct_id and
        pd1.parameter_type = 'Asset' and
        pd2.parameter_type = 'Indication' join
     pivot_dummy pd3
     on pd1.nct_id = pd3.nct_id and
        pd3.parameter_type = 'BMx' join
     pivot_dummy pd4
     on pd1.nct_id = pd4.nct_id and
        pd4.parameter_type = 'LOT';
```

This only works for ids that have all four values.  Switching to a `full join` solves the problem -- but complicates the query.

I think the best solution is a `left join` that looks like this:

```
select pd.nct_id, pd1.parameter_value as asset, pd2.parameter_value as indication,
       pd3.parameter_value as BMx, pd4.parameter_value as LOT
from (select distinct nct_id from pivot_dummy
     ) pd left join
     pivot_dummy pd1
     on pd1.nct_id = pd.nct_id and
        pd1.parameter_type = 'Asset' left join
     pivot_dummy pd2
     on pd2.nct_id = pd.nct_id and
        pd2.parameter_type = 'Indication' left join
     pivot_dummy pd3
     on pd3.nct_id = pd.nct_id and
        pd3.parameter_type = 'BMx' left join
     pivot_dummy pd4
     on pd4.nct_id = pd.nct_id and
        pd4.parameter_type = 'LOT';
```